# Not recieving any data, but sending - Hamachi

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc, hamachi

My friend has created a Hamachi server (open to LAN) on Minecraft. Every time I join, I have the same issue: I can move around the world, dig, attack... and he sees me do so, but I don't see anything moving. I don't see mobs moving, can't pick-up blocks (they don't even get out of destroyed blocks). I need a solution to get it working.

We're playing on Minecraft 1.7.10. Same thing happened with vanilla, even if we're trying to play Tekkit Legends (through Technic Launcher).

We both have bought the original version of game.

Answer (score 0):

Hamachi is a bit tricky sometimes:

Have you and your friend opened the required Hamachi and Minecraft ports on your routers? Do you both use the same version of Hamachi and Minecraft?

If that doesn't work at all id suggest you to try other programs like Tunngle or GameRanger.